# Unable to connect with MQTT broker in Apache Camel inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, apache-camel

I have a project with Apache camel, and it requires mqtt broker for connection. If I run mqtt broker (mosquitto) in docker and execute my project locally it is working totally fine but when I am running the project through Dockerfile i.e. making an executable jar and executing it on docker it says **"Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"** even though mqtt broker is up and running.

Full logs (exception):

```
    [main] ERROR org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Error starting CamelContext (camel-1) due to exception thrown: Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeException(RuntimeCamelException.java:66)
at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.doFail(BaseService.java:413)
at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.fail(BaseService.java:342)
at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:132)
at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.startService(AbstractCamelContext.java:3597)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:401)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartRouteConsumers(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:319)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:213)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:3299)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2951)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2902)
at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2586)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:247)
at basyx.components.databridge.core.component.UpdaterComponent.startRoutes(UpdaterComponent.java:68)
at basyx.components.databridge.core.component.UpdaterComponent.startComponent(UpdaterComponent.java:62)
at basyx.components.databridge.executable.UpdaterExecutable.main(UpdaterExecutable.java:73)
Caused by: Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:80)
 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:724)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
 at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
 at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
 at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:74)
 ... 2 more
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.14.0 (camel-1) shutting down (timeout:45s)
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Routes stopped (total:2 stopped:2)
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext -     Stopped route2 (paho://PropertyB)
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext -     Stopped route1 (paho://Properties)
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.14.0 (camel-1) shutdown in 14ms (uptime:238ms)
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
 at org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeException(RuntimeCamelException.java:66)
 at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.doFail(BaseService.java:413)
 at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.fail(BaseService.java:342)
 at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:132)
 at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.startService(AbstractCamelContext.java:3597)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:401)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartRouteConsumers(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:319)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:213)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:3299)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2951)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2902)
 at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2586)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:247)
 at basyx.components.databridge.core.component.UpdaterComponent.startRoutes(UpdaterComponent.java:68)
 at basyx.components.databridge.core.component.UpdaterComponent.startComponent(UpdaterComponent.java:62)
 at basyx.components.databridge.executable.UpdaterExecutable.main(UpdaterExecutable.java:73)
Caused by: Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:80)
 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:724)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
 at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
 at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
 at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:74)
 ... 2 more
```

**My docker compose file:**

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  bridge-service:
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\user\temp:/usr/share/config
    depends_on:
      mqtt:
        condition: service_healthy

  mqtt:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.15
    ports:
      - 1884:1884
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\user\temp\mosquitto:/mosquitto/config
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", mosquitto_sub -p 1884 -t 'topic' -C 1 -E -i probe -W 3]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 2
      start_period: 10s
      timeout: 5s
```

I am sure that this is due to docker because even if I am running jar file locally it is working fine.

Please help if anyone has any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching over internet, I added `network_mode: host` to service bridge-service and everything worked fine.

So in order to communicate between two services like explained scenario in the problem above just add `network_mode: host` and everything would work.

Now the updated docker compose file is:

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  bridge-service:
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\user\temp:/usr/share/config
    depends_on:
      mqtt:
        condition: service_healthy

  mqtt:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.15
    ports:
      - 1884:1884
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\user\temp\mosquitto:/mosquitto/config
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", mosquitto_sub -p 1884 -t 'topic' -C 1 -E -i probe -W 3]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 2
      start_period: 10s
      timeout: 5s
```